# How can I dispatch one action, wait 1 second, then dispatch two more actions in Redux Observable?

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

How would I do the following in a single epic

1. Dispatch pauseGame()
2. Wait 1 second
3. Dispatch 2 actions

The following dispatches the last two actions but not pauseGame().

[image]

```
const moveEpic: RootEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(move)),
    map(() => pauseGame()),
    filter(() => state$.value.ruleRow.lastMoveSuccessful),
    delay(1000),
    switchMap(() => [
      removeBoardObject(
        state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory[state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory.length - 1]
          .dragged,
      ),
      resumeGame(),
    ]),
  );
```

Comment: Define "close but not working.", what happens? what error are you getting?

Comment: pauseGame does not dispatch but the last two actions in switchMap do. It skips pauseGame().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `pauseGame` isn't dispatching is because you're not dispatching it. You're calling the action creator and then immediately changing your observable state to `lastMoveSuccessful`.

Instead, what you want is to split the pipeline and `merge` them back to one. I know this is confusing, but it's how Redux-Observable works at the moment. If you want a different way where you can dispatch at any point in time, checkout my article: https://dev.to/sawtaytoes/the-best-practice-anti-pattern-jj6

When the `move` type occurs, switch to a new observable. That observable is a merging of 2 new observables: one which immediately dispatches `pauseGame`, the other which checks if the last move was successful, and if so, waits a second and dispatches 2 other actions.

```ts
const moveEpic: RootEpic = (action$, state$) => (
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(move)),
    switchMap(() => (
      merge(
        of(pauseGame()),
        of(state$.value.ruleRow.lastMoveSuccessful).pipe(
          filter(Boolean),
          delay(1000),
          concatMap(() => [
            removeBoardObject(
              state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory[
                state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory.length - 1
              ].dragged
            ),
            resumeGame(),
          ]),
        )
      )
    )),
  );
)
```

As a side note, I don't know why you've created your own `isActionOf` function, but normally you should be able to change that line to `ofType(move)` instead.

Evert Bouw provided a simpler suggestion utilizing `startWith` and `endWith`. You'll lose sequential ordering in your pipeline, but you don't have to split it:

```ts
const moveEpic: RootEpic = (action$, state$) => (
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(move)),
    switchMap(() => (
        of(state$.value.ruleRow.lastMoveSuccessful).pipe(
          filter(Boolean),
          delay(1000),
          map(() => (
            removeBoardObject(
              state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory[
                state$.value.ruleRow.totalMoveHistory.length - 1
              ].dragged
          )),
          startWith(pauseGame()),
          endWith(resumeGame()),
        )
      )
    )),
  );
)
```

Keep in mind, if you needed to know the value of `state$` in `endWith`, you'd want to use `finalize` instead. It takes a function instead of a value.

Comment: To answer why I have isActionOf and instead of ofType, isActionOf is from the typesafe-actions library. It does exactly the same as ofType, but it will help type the next item in pipe.